# Shortcut for finding variance proof

Tags: statistics

One of the questions in my textbook asks to prove that

$$s^2 = \frac {1}{n-1} \left[\sum _{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 - n\bar x^2\right]$$

where $s^2$ is the sample variance and $\bar x$ is the sample mean.

My attempt:

I know by definition

$$s^2 = \frac {1}{n-1} \left[\sum _{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \bar x)^2\right]$$

Expanding

$$s^2 = \frac {1}{n-1} \left[\sum _{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 - 2x_i \bar x + \bar x^2\right]$$

Multiplying $2x_i \bar x$ by $\frac n n$

$$s^2 = \frac {1}{n-1} \left[\sum _{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 - 2n\bar x^2 + \bar x^2\right]$$

This is where I get stuck. I feel like I'm close to proving this but I don't know how to simplify any further. If only the last term $\bar x^2$ had an n then I can add the last two terms up and get what I need. I'm probably making some silly mistake, so would appreciate someone helping me out

Comment: You are making a silly mistake: the $\overline{x}^2$ term gets added $n$times, and should therefore be $n\overline{x}^2$

Comment: @voldemort Haha, I knew I made a mistake. Thanks for finding it for me :)